# Insert value JSON with foreach?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I want insert this value JSON to database, but with following PHP code it insert just `[` in table. how can fix this problem?

Html code:

```
<input name="start_date[]" value="2012/08/07">
<input name="start_date[]" value="2011/10/29">
<input name="percent[]" value="56">
```

**This value JSON**: `["2012\/08\/07","2011\/10\/29"]`

PHP code:

```
    $start_date         = json_encode($this->input->post('start_date'));
    $percent       = $this->input->post('percent');

            print_r($start_date); // This output is as: ["2012\/08\/07","2011\/10\/29"]

            $data = array();
            foreach ($percent as $idx => $name) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'start_date' => $start_date[$idx],
                    'price_change' => $percent[$idx]
                );
            };                
            $this->db->insert_batch('table', $data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I don't understand what you trying to achieve but I give it a go. Does this help if you just remove "[$idx]" from your $start_date. So record to database would look like:

```
$data[] = array(
    'start_date' => $start_date,
    'price_change' => $percent[$idx]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `"` may be confusing it. I can't tell what kind of database system you're using, but maybe you should try escaping the `"` to `\"` (with the help of `addslashes()`) and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: No, I can insert this value without use from foreach but with foreach inserted just this: `[`. i use mysql.

Comment: Oh, well, `$start_date` is a string. You need to run `json_decode` on it first before you can start accessing it like an array.

Comment: i want insert it in database as json`["2012\/08\/07","2011\/10\/29"]`, how is it?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know how `$percent` is being set.

Comment: Okay, and what does `var_dump($start_date,$percent);` give you? Is it a pair of arrays? Or a pair of strings?

Comment: this is output var_dump: `string(31) "["2012\/08\/07","2011\/10\/29"]" array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "56" } ["2012\/08\/07","2011\/10\/29"]`

Comment: Okay, I have no idea how your form stuff is set up then. Seems very confusing to me - what's wrong with `$_POST`?